# Is the Wikipedia depiction of the ergosphere of a Kerr black hole a Cassini oval?

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

Glancing at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rotating_black_hole&oldid=930769965)) I thought that the frontier of the ergosphere appearing in the picture at the beginning of the considered article looks very much like a Cassini oval. Is it actually one? If yes, how can we prove it?

Comment: Now posted on [mathoverflow.se]: [Is the Wikipedia depiction of the ergosphere of a Kerr black hole a Cassini oval?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/348547)

Answer (score 1):

No, the geometry of that region is not exactly a Cassini oval. The following figure shows the geometry of the Kerr space-time with the proper nomenclature of the relevant surfaces:

[image]

Note that there are two horizons two surfaces of infinite redshift. For a Kerr black hole of mass $M$ and spin $a$, the horizon surfaces are given by
$$r_h^\pm=M\pm\sqrt{M^2-a^2}$$
and the surfaces of infinite redshift are given by
$$r_e^\pm=M\pm\sqrt{M^2-a^2\cos^2\theta}$$
where the plus and minus sign refers to the outer and inner surfaces respectively and $\theta$ is the zenith angle. The above figure is a *side-view* of the geometry plotted in the $yz-$plane which can be rotated about the $z-$axis to get the complete 3-dimensional picture. One can plot two equations (for a fixed value of the spin parameter $-M\leq a\leq M$) as a function of $\theta$ to obtain the above figure.

**EDIT:**

For a more technical explanation, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/348579/150787) to the same question cross-posted on MathOverflow.